# Find the number of customers waiting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, queue

`df` is a pandas dataframe which contains the customer data for a retail shop. The key columns in `df` are `customer_arrival_time` and `service_completion_time`. A small sample is given below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2019-12-16 12:30, 2019-12-16 13:28], [2019-12-16 12:48, 2019-12-16 13:15], [2019-12-16 13:00, 2019-12-16 13:30]], columns=['customer_arrival_time', 'service_completion_time'])
```

I am trying to calculate the queue length at the time of each customer arrival using the following code:

```
df['current_queue_length'] = 0
for index_1 in (0, len(df)):
    count = 0
    for index_2 in (0, len(df)):
        if df['customer_arrival_time'][index_1]>df['customer_arrival_time'][index_2] and df['customer_arrival_time'][index_1]<df['service_completion_time'][index_2]:
            count = count+1
    df['current_queue_length'][index_1] = count
```

The new column results for the given example should be: `[0 1 2]`

However, the code is running for a very long time without completion, possibly due to the large dataset (approx 100,000 customer arrivals). Is there a more efficient way to obtain the desired values?

Note: I have also sorted the data based on the arrival times. Can I somehow use this feature for additional advantage?

Comment: In the sorted data frame you know that the number of people waiting when the j-th customer arrives is `j-len(df.loc[(df.service_completion_time<df.customer_arrival_time[j]])`. It feels like this is not optimal yet but this should be faster than the double loop you have so far.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWierichs . I found a more accurate solution using `for index_1, row_1 in df.iterrows()`. I had to wait for a few minutes to get the results using 
`df.loc[index_1, 'current_queue_length'] = len(df[ (df['customer_arrival_time']<df.loc[index_1, 'customer_arrival_time']) & (df['service_completion_time']>df.loc[index_1, 'customer_arrival_time']) ])`